Script Font gets cut off in iOS when transformed
I have used Sloop Script on my site and only the Script Font shows some very weird behavior. This only seems to happen on iOS.
The Font is cut off - either horizontally (e.g. hover in Navigation) or vertically (e.g. right under header-section) but only when the elements have some sort of transform-property.
Does anybody know how this can be fixed? Thanks in advance!
Line-Height can be adjusted or vertical problem can be fixed with padding and negative margins to some extend, however horizontal problem still remains.

You can see this on https://michaelaust.github.io/portfolio/

FYI: A workaround i found, was to just give padding and negative margin to each letter or word. Not the cleanest way, though.
